# HTML5 video element does not restart a live stream at its live point if I pause it

Tags: android, ios, html, video, live-streaming

As a viewer, I expect that if I pause a live stream, when I unpause it, it will restart from the latest live point.

Instead, on HTML5 video elements, the restart point is just where the stream left off - i.e. it's no longer live.

That's a problem for live streaming as what's more important to the viewer is to stay up to date with what's happening now rather than catch up on stuff he may have missed.

Please note that removing controls is not possible in iOS (so the issue will arise for a large number of mobile devices) and that HTML5 is a requirement (at least for my purposes) for any newer mobile devices on Android and iOS.

Has anyone cracked this problem?

Comment: What protocol do you use for the live stream? HLS? DASH?

Comment: How long do you keep the player paused? If it's just a few seconds then I find it completely normal for the stream to resume where it left off.  If it's paused for a few minutes then maybe the player had a few seconds buffered and it first plays them and only then it skips to the front of the stream.